# MySQL a single update statement (+) =

Tags: mysql, sql-update

This is an oracle statement and I can't get this join to run in mySQL

```
update dept x
set totsal = (select sum(nvl(sal,0))
from emp e,dept d
where e.deptno(+) = d.deptno
and x.deptno = e.deptno);
```

and the output should be

```
Deptno    Dname      Loc      Totsal

10    ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK    8750
20    RESEARCH     DALLAS    10875
30    SALES     CHICAGO    9400
40    OPERATIONS  BOSTON    0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql should be

```
    update dept x
    INNER JOIN (
    select d.deptno, sum(ifnull(e.sal,0)) totsal
    from dept  d
    left join emp  e  ON  e.deptno = d.deptno
    GROUP BY d.deptno
    ) t on t.deptno = x.deptno
    set x.totsal = t.totsal
```

Comment: thanks a lot this solved the problem (typo: x.deptno)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use outdated join syntax with `(+)` in MySql.

Instead you should join `dept` to this query:

```
select deptno, sum(sal) totsal
from emp
group by deptno
```

which returns the total salary for each department:

```
update dept d
left join (
  select deptno, sum(sal) totsal
  from emp
  group by deptno
) e on e.deptno = d.deptno
set d.totsal = coalesce(e.totsal, 0)
```

But I believe that it is simpler like this:

```
update dept d
set d.totsal = coalesce((select sum(e.sal) from emp e where e.deptno = d.deptno), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this,, it's really helpful